# Decompose a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to decompose a string with JavaScript.

The initial String:

```
$var="1234 => 4242,Example Mailbox,root@localhost"
```

The 4 decomposed parts:

```
1234
4242
Example Mailbox
root@localhost
```

What is a more efficient way: to use a regular expression or to call string functions?

Can someone please provide a regex to extract such patterns, probably by using groups.

Comment: Regex is more efficient way.

Comment: Efficient in term of what? Lines of code? Execution time?

Comment: That does look much like PHP, not JavaScript?

Comment: By the way, string functions can accept regular expressions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a solution that is a little less restrictive :

```
$var.split(/\s*,\s*|\s*=>\s*/)
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want use the [string `split` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) together with a simple (and fast) regular expression:

```
var vals = $var.split(/,|\s*=>\s*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work, assuming that the first two groups are integers and the rest can be anything (except for commas)

```
([0-9]+) => ([0-9]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)
```